# What's the most complete and heavy in features free calendar software with scheduling capabilities

Tags: php, calendar, scheduling

I"m looking for a completely free calendar software with decent to lots of scheduling capabilities. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really there's a bunch out there, but you might want to take a look at [PHP-Calendar](http://www.php-calendar.com/) to get started.